# Invariant ring of the subvariety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, invariant-theory, geometric-invariant-theory

Let $G$ be a linearly reductive algebraic group and $X$ be an affine $G$-variety over an algebraically closed field $\mathbb{K}$. Let $Y\subset X$ be a (closed) affine subvariety of $X$ which is also $G$-stable.

> Is there any "nice" description of the invariant ring $\mathbb{K}[Y]^G$ in terms of the invariant ring $\mathbb{K}[X]^G$? Maybe something like- it's a quotient or a subring of $\mathbb{K}[X]^G$.

For my situation, $X$ is an affine space.

Comment: Under your hypotheses, isn't $\mathbb K[Y]^G$ the quotient of $\mathbb K[X]^G$ by the $G$-fixed vectors in the ideal $I_{Y \subseteq X}$ of functions in $\mathbb K[X]$ vanishing on $Y$?  At least this seems so as vector spaces, since linear reductivity implies that there is a $G$-module splitting of $0 \to I_{Y \subseteq X} \to \mathbb K[X] \to \mathbb K[Y] \to 0$.

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/439458/invariant-ring-of-the-subvariety#comment1133475_439458), assuming you meant $Y$ to be $G$-stable.  Otherwise, I don't know what $\mathbb K[Y]^G$ means.

Comment: @LSpice Thanks for your reply. Yes, I meant $Y$ is $G$-stable. For my situation, $X$ is an affine space. Also, can you give some kind of reference for the exact sequence that you've mentioned.

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/439458/invariant-ring-of-the-subvariety#comment1133478_439458), for me, the exact sequence I [mentioned](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/439458/invariant-ring-of-the-subvariety#comment1133475_439458) is the *definition* of a closed subvariety of an affine variety.  Could you say what is your definition?

Comment: @LSpice I meant the fact about the "$G$-module splitting". Sorry, I should have been more precise.

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/439458/invariant-ring-of-the-subvariety#comment1133481_439458), this is, again, for me the definition of linear reductivity:  that every $G$-representation is completely reducible; and the definition of complete reducibility is that every stable subspace has a stable complement.  Again, if you use another definition, could you tell me what it is so that I can see if I can find a source for the equivalence?

Comment: @LSpice Thanks for your explanation. I use the same definition. It's just that I didn't observe it in terms of the exact sequence, but I see it now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As we discussed in the comments, by linear reductivity of $G$, there is a $G$-module splitting of the surjection $\mathbb K[X] \to \mathbb K[Y]$; so the restriction map $\mathbb K[X]^G \to \mathbb K[Y]^G$ is a surjection.  Thus $\mathbb K[Y]^G$ is a quotient of $\mathbb K[X]^G$, as both a $G$-module and an algebra; and is a $G$-submodule of $\mathbb K[X]^G$, but (even if $G$ is trivial) need not be a subalgebra.